# Any metric space is isometric to a subspace of some complete metric space

Tags: metric-spaces, solution-verification

Let $S$ be any nonvoid set and let $B(S)$ denote the set of all complex valued functions $f$ on $S$ such that $$|| f||_u = \sup \lbrace |f(x)|: x\in S \rbrace < \infty.$$

The metric if $B(S)$ is $||f-g||_u$ for $f,g\in B(S)$. Now let $S$ be any metric space with metric $\rho$. Let $p\in S$ be fixed. For $s\in S$ define $f_s$ on $S$ by $$f_s(x) = (\rho(x,s)-\rho(x,p)).$$ Prove that me mapping $s\rightarrow f_s$ is an isometry of $S$ into $B(S)$; i.e. $$||f_s - f_t||_u = \rho(s,t)$$ for all $s,t\in S$.

I can obtain in a more or less straightforward manner that $||f_s-f_t||_u\leq \rho(s,t)$. My questions is, is it valid to say that, since $t$ is given, I can set $\tilde{p}=t$ and $$\rho(s,t) \leq \sup |\rho(x,s)-\rho(x,t)|?$$ (It seems to me that everything can be reduced to a quadrilateral in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with a "moving vertex" $x$.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\rho(s,t)$ is the same as $|\rho(x,s)-\rho(x,t)|$ when $x=s$, so $\rho(s,t)$ is an element of $\{|\rho(x,s)-\rho(x,t)| : x \in S\}$ and then $$\rho(s,t) \leq \sup\{|\rho(x,s)-\rho(x,t)| : x \in S\} = \|f_s-f_t\|_u.$$